# escaping symbolic characters in strings programmatically (zsh)

Tags: escaping

I am finding that certain characters need to escaped when run through commands.

For example

If I have a command

```
command "/Users/blah/abcd[1]"
```

This doesnt work

If I escape the command and run it as

```
command "/Users/blah/abcd\[1\]"
```

it works.

However, I have files with 100s of lines containing lines like this ""/Users/blah/abcd[1]""

While I can replace "[" with "[" and "]" with "]", is there a better way to do this?

I have tried escaping the individual characters, but its very laborious and errorprone.